# Build issues on Centos6

Tags: linux, build, centos6, centos5

I have to migrate software suite called [Rivermuse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rivermuse-core/) from CentOS5 to CentOS6. The README file suggest the following steps:

Directory setup:

1. mkdir GNUbuild rpmbuild archive
2. rpmdev-setuptree

Build:

1. autoreconf -vfi
2. ./configure
3. make dist-rpm
4. make createrepo

The following error occurs during step 3 of the build process:

```
Processing files: angara-perl-Omosd-4.2.2-9.el6.i386
error: File not found: /home/cas/sandbox/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/angara-4.2.2-9.el6.i386/usr/src
error: File not found: /home/cas/sandbox/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/angara-4.2.2-9.el6.i386/usr/lib/debug
error: File not found: /home/cas/sandbox/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/angara-4.2.2-9.el6.i386/usr/share/man/man3/Omosd.3pm.gz
```

The BUILDROOT directory does not get generated or used in the build process on CentOS5. The online sources we've come across (such as the Fedora RPM guide) haven't been very useful for our specific case.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can the down voter please comment on why the question was down voted? Surely I can't be the only one who has had difficulty building packages on CentOS6 that I could build perfectly well on CentOS5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out by going through the .spec files.

In the angara.spec file there was an if statement that evaluated whether the OS was fedora or Redhat. I modified this if statement to always run the fedora section, since fedora is redhat's upstream counterpart and a newer version of redhat/centos would have incorporated what was originally only available in fedora, and necessitated the if statement in the first place. I also had to comment out the following:

1. %exclude /usr/src
2. %exclude /usr/lib/debug

And I had to add the following just below the lines mentioned above:

1. /usr/local/share/perl5/Omosd.pm.conf
2. /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Omosd/.packlist
3. /usr/local/share/perl5/Omosd.pm.in

I guess this info will only be applicable to rivermuse users, hopefully someone finds this useful..